# Can any function be expressed as a repeated composition of another function?

Tags: functions

Let a function $f$ be on $R^n$ into $R^n$ and let k be a positive integer. Proposition: There exist a function $g$ on $R^n$ into $R^n$ such that $f$ equals $g$ composed $k$ times with itself:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \underbrace{g(g(\cdots g(}_{k}x)\cdots)) \\
&= g^k(x)
\end{align}
If this is false, then under what conditions does such a function $g$ exist? In either case, if a $g$ exists, then can something be said about the complexity of the function $g$? For example, if $f$ is composed of elementary functions, then $g$ is composed of elementary functions?

I am wondering because when formulating a prediction one can either formulate a 1-step prediction and then derive a k-step prediction, or directly formulate a k-step prediction. If the proposition is false, then there can exist cases where a k-step prediction is better than any compostion of 1-step predictions. Furthermore, if $g$ is in general "more complex" than $f$, then it may in some applications be motivated to first try formulating a k-step prediction.

Comment: If there is no restriction in $f$, then for $n=1, k = 2$ there is a simple counterexample with $f(-1) = 1, f(1) = -1, f(x) = x$ if $x\notin \{-1,1\}$. I don't know enough to answer the rest. By the way, these functions are called "Iterated function".